# Android,How to start a new Activity from a dialog?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to Start a new activity from my custom dialog, I have a simple Button and I want that when I press the button a new activity will start.

I try with Start:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(arg0.getContext(),IdResult.class);     
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

but it doesn't work; how can I make this work?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Are you getting any exceptions? Is your Intent constructor's first parameter an activity context?

Comment: check for mainfest entry of your activity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start an activity from a dialog in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070618/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-dialog-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 public class CustomDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
      Button okButton, cancelButton;
      Activity mActivity;

      public CustomDialog(Activity activity) {      
        super(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {       
        if (v == cancelButton)
            dismiss();
        else {
            Intent i = new Intent(mActivity, IdResult.class);
            mActivity.startActivity(i);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you start new activity from non-activity class. 
Just add `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

You can read more in [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

just add the this code inside the custom dialog

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ItemSelection.class);
mActivity.startActivity(i);
```